# getByRole query for paragraph not working during React testing

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have created a simple counter app for learning `react testing library`. But I got stuck when I was testing whether a paragraph is rendered or not with `{count}` text.

Main.jsx

```
function Main() {
  const [Count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleCount() {
    setCount((c) => c + 1);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter App</h1>
      <Counter count={Count} />
      <Button label="Click me" handleCount={handleCount} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Counter.jsx

```
function Counter({ count }) {
  return <p>{count}</p>;
}
```

Main.spec.jsx

```
it("should render count", () => {
    render(<Main />);
    expect(screen.getByRole("paragraph")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This test was not enough to get passed. I know that we can add `data-testid` to `<p>` DOM node and then we can test this by `getByTestId` query. But I want to know why my above test case which uses `getByRole('paragraph')`is getting fail every time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`getByRole` uses the HTML role of different elements. Paragraph is not a valid role, that's why your query doesn't work. You can read more here about `getByRole` https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#byrole and about the different roles in html here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance.

You could for example use `getByText` instead to achieve what you want (read more about preferred queries here: https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query/).

```js
expect(screen.getByText("0")).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: What would be the valid role for the paragraph?

Comment: `p` tags doesn't have an implicit role (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) so you have to add a role yourself using `aria-role` if you want it to have a role. I'm not sure actually which roles would fit, I guess that's very dependant on context.

Comment: The linked w3 document indicates that `paragraph` *is* a valid role and the implicit role for a `<p>`. The role was [added to ARIA in June 2018](https://github.com/w3c/aria/commit/907b62da80bf3fb8bbd18768b8f9fa6ca99e1fa8)

Comment: I should probably acknowledge that, as indicated by @Thejool, MDN incorrectly indicates that `<p>` has no implicit ARIA role but the [ARIA documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-p) shows `paragraph`.

Comment: Checking in to add that as of September 2023 `screen.getByRole("paragraph")` cannot find `p` elements despite it being a valid role. [Someone opened an issue in June and it will be fixed in React Testing Library as soon as `aria-query` releases a new version with the fix in that repo](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/1234).

Answer (score 1):

getByText: Outside of forms, text content is the main way users find elements. This method can be used to find non-interactive elements (like divs, spans, and paragraphs)

Check TL Documentation
https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#byrole